# Survey weights and population size

Tags: survey, population, survey-weights

When doing complex survey design, does weights necessarily gross up the data to the whole population size or just up to a certain level, e.g. 50% of the actual population?

Comment: hi, most public use surveys contain weights that sum to the generalizable population.  if they don't, they still need to scale up proportionally to that population count

Comment: @Anthony Damico Thank you for answering. However, I have found the solution to my "bizarre" problem. The population size I get after applying weights is the eligible population (age > 15). The problem was I was comparing this number to the whole population.